# How to use ActiveModel::Serializer with a PostgreSQL JSON column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, active-model-serializers

I am trying to use [ActiveModel::Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) in conjunction with a PostgreSQL database.

The problem I am having is that whenever I include a `json` type column in a serializer I get:

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70
```

I don't want to do [this](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2014/05/27/avoid-rails-when-generating-json-responses-with-postgresql.html) as I need access to the data before returning it.

From `schema.rb`:

```
create_table "jobs", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "tool"
    t.string   "name"
    t.json     "options"
    t.integer  "status"
    t.string   "version"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

`job_serializer.rb`:

```
class JobSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
    attributes :id, :tool, :name, :status, :options, :version, :created_at

    has_many :inputs, serializer: FileLinkSerializer
end
```

Works fine if I remove `:options` from the attributes but crashes when it is included as above.

Comment: I was just wondering how serializers might behave with a json column, made a quick serch and there we go :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with having a field named `options`. I wrapped that field in a field called called `tool_options` and everything worked fine.

```
class JobSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id, :tool, :name, :status, :tool_options, :version, :created_at
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  def tool_options
    options
  end
end
```

(In reality I'll be changing my schema as its not too late.)

Comment: Just came across the same issue in active_model_serializers 0.8. It doesn't happen in 0.9 as the clashing options feature seems to have been removed.